# Costume Redirect Controller to other site not working

Tags: magento2.2

I have written custom redirect controller to for affiliate site but it is not working.

Following is my code:
Helper

```
namespace Test\AffiliateProduct\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

    public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
    }

    public function getRedirectUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product) {
        return Mage::getUrl('affiliate/redirect/product', array('id' => $product->getId()));
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace Test\AffiliateProduct\Controller;

class Redirect extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    protected $affiliateProductHelper;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $generic;
    protected $catalogProductFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \OfferDeal\AffiliateProduct\Helper\Data $affiliateProductHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\Generic $generic,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $catalogProductFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
        $this->affiliateProductHelper = $affiliateProductHelper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->generic = $generic;
        $this->catalogProductFactory = $catalogProductFactory;

    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $product = $this->catalogProductFactory->create()->load($productId);

        if (($product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product)
            && ($product->getTypeId() === \Test\AffiliateProduct\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_AFFILIATE)
        ) {
            if (!\Zend_Uri::check($product->getAffiliateLink())) {
                $this->generic->addError(
                    $this->helper->__('The partner product is not accessible.')
                );

                $this->goBack();
                return;
            }

            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl($product->getAffiliateLink());

            //$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($product->getAffiliateLink());
            //return;

        } else {
            $this->generic->addError(
                $this->helper->__('Affiliate product not found')
            );

            $this->goBack();
            return;
        }

    }
    protected function goBack()
    {
        $returnUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();

        if ($returnUrl) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
        } else {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

View 
Add to Cart phtml

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Shop Now'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('Test\AffiliateProduct\Helper\Data'); ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
<div class="add-to-cart">
        <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<?php
            echo helper->getRedirectUrl($_product);?>'; return false;">
            <span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span>
        </button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Can someone help in figureing out what is wrong with for Magento 2 redirect controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mage::getUrl()`)  is **wrong code**.

You should use

```
$this->_getUrl('affiliate/redirect/product', array('id' => $product->getId()))
```

IN helper

Comment: It is getting HTTP ERROR 500. I am not sure where and how to debug this.

Comment: I have fix 500 error and now i can see the controller is redirecting to affiliate/redirect/product/id/4/ URL but the issue is 404 and not forwarded to the url.

Comment: I have fixed this controller as it was not loading. Thanks for the help it works now.

Comment: You welcome ...